# list filter by custom list display field in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have following model admin. I'm displaying custom field in list view.

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'state')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    list_filter = ('state',)
    def state(self, obj):
        address = Address.objects.filter(owner=obj.id)
        if address:
            return address.state
    return None
```

I tried above but it gives an error "list_filter[0]' refers to 'state' which does not refer to a Field."
So I want filter records by state. So how I can do this in django 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

list_filter works on related models.

If model looks like that:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Customer, models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='address')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

You can use address__state in ModelAdmin. For example:

```
@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'state')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    list_filter = ('address__state', )
```

**Note that list_display doesn't work this way!**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. In `django.admin.views`, when collecting filter fields happens this:

```
if not isinstance(field, Field):
   field_path = field
   field = get_fields_from_path(self.model, field_path)[-1]
```

So, `state` is not a `Field` instance, but a function that returns string or None. Then as you can see, Django tries to add fields to `list_filter` anyway, assuming it is not a `Field` instance, but can be path to model field.
Eventually it adds `state` to `list_filter`, and then goes to `django.db.models.options.Options` to retrieve instance of field.

```
try:
    # Retrieve field instance by name from cached or just-computed
    # field map.
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
except KeyError:
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
```

As you see, Django can not see this field in model and throws an Exception. This Exception is handled by `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand`, that converts error message to `"list_filter[0]' refers to 'state' which does not refer to a Field."`

Answer (score -4):

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'state')
list_filter = ('state',)
search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

def state(self, obj):
    address = Address.objects.filter(owner=obj.id)
    if address:
        return address.state
return None
```

You should include list_filter if you want to filter

Comment: This will not work for custom field. It gives an error CustomerAdmin.list_filter[0]' refers to 'state' which does not refer to a Field. Because state is not a field in Customer model and also there is no relation between Address model and Customer model.